# Return value changes partially and deterministically

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, iterator

I'm implementing a custom `cend` operator that returns what I consider a null letter. The const_iterator's constructor created a const_iterator that stores as a private data member a pointer to the letter `Letter` passed as an argument.

I'm using a loop that checks if a cons_iterator is different from `cend`, which becomes infinite because `it` is never equal to `cend`. I've debugged the program with gdb and have found that `it` reaches a null letter I actually store in the tree, which is the intended behaviour and is correct. I've also debugged the `Letter ()` constructor and it returns a correct null letter:

I don't have any random behaviours with the other data members, so I figure this must be an error in my implementation, but I don't know what it can be.

Here's a MRE:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

/*
 * LETTER'S HEADER
 */

class Letter {
private:
    char    grafema;
    bool    concluye;
    Letter* sister;
    Letter* daughter;
    Letter* mother;

public:
    Letter  ();
    Letter  (char g, bool c, Letter & m);
    Letter  (char g, bool c);

    char    Grafema  () const;
    bool    Null     () const;
    Letter* Sister   () const;
    Letter* Daughter () const;
    Letter* Mother   () const;

    void SetSister   (Letter & h);
    void SetDaughter (Letter & h);

    bool operator == (const Letter & other) const;
};

/*
 * TREELETTERS' HEADER
 */

class TreeLetters {
public:
    class const_iterator;

private:
    Letter* root;

public:
    TreeLetters  (char g, bool c);

    Letter* Raiz();

    TreeLetters::const_iterator cbegin () const;
    TreeLetters::const_iterator cend   () const;

    class const_iterator {
    private:
        const Letter* it;

    public:
        const_iterator ();
        const_iterator (Letter letter);

        bool operator == (const TreeLetters::const_iterator & other) const;

        const Letter   & operator *  ();
        const_iterator & operator ++ ();
    };
};

/*
 * LETRAS'S METHODS
 */

Letter :: Letter ()
    :grafema  ('\0'),
     concluye (false),
     sister   (nullptr),
     daughter (nullptr),
     mother   (nullptr)
{ }

Letter :: Letter (char g, bool c, Letter & m)
    :grafema  (g),
     concluye (c),
     sister   (nullptr),
     daughter (nullptr),
     mother   (&m)
{ }

Letter :: Letter (char g, bool c)
    :grafema  (g),
     concluye (c),
     sister   (nullptr),
     daughter (nullptr),
     mother   (nullptr)
{ }

void Letter :: SetSister (Letter & h) {
    if (!sister) {
        sister = &h;
    }
    else {
        Letter* aux = sister;
        sister = &h;
        h.sister = aux;
    }
}

void Letter :: SetDaughter (Letter & h) {
    if (!daughter) {
        daughter = &h;
    }
    else if (daughter->Null()) {
        Letter* aux = daughter;
        daughter = &h;
        h.daughter = aux;
    }
}

char Letter :: Grafema () const {
    return grafema;
}

bool Letter :: Null () const {
    return !grafema && !concluye && !sister && !daughter && !mother;
}

Letter* Letter :: Sister () const {
    return sister;
}

Letter* Letter :: Daughter () const {
    return daughter;
}

Letter* Letter :: Mother () const {
    return mother;
}

bool Letter :: operator == (const Letter & other) const {
    return grafema  == other.grafema
        && concluye == other.concluye
        && sister  == other.sister
        && daughter     == other.daughter
        && mother    == other.mother;
}

TreeLetters :: TreeLetters (char g, bool c) {
    root = new Letter(g, c);
}

Letter* TreeLetters :: Raiz () {
    return root;
}

TreeLetters::const_iterator TreeLetters :: cbegin () const {
    return const_iterator(*root);
}

TreeLetters::const_iterator TreeLetters :: cend () const {
    return const_iterator(Letter());
}

TreeLetters::const_iterator :: const_iterator (Letter letter)
    :it (&letter)
{ }

bool TreeLetters::const_iterator :: operator ==
                               (const TreeLetters::const_iterator & other) const {
    return *it == *other.it;
}

const Letter & TreeLetters::const_iterator :: operator * () {
    return *it;
}

TreeLetters::const_iterator & TreeLetters::const_iterator :: operator ++ () {
    if (!it->Null()) {
        if (it->Daughter()) {
            it = (it->Daughter());
        }
        else {
            while (!it->Sister() && it->Mother())
                it = (it->Mother());

            it = (it->Sister());
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

/*
 * MAIN TEST METHOD
 *
 * Creates a tree with this structure:
 *
 *          a -- null_letter
 *          |
 *          b
 *
 * This is how the tree is created with the other methods (and works well).
 */

int main () {
    TreeLetters tree('a', false);

    Letter null_letter,
          daughter('b', true, *tree.Raiz());

    tree.Raiz()->SetSister(null_letter);
    tree.Raiz()->SetDaughter(daughter);

    TreeLetters::const_iterator iter = tree.cbegin();

    while (!(iter == tree.cend())) {
        printf ("-> %s\n", "found one");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I hope I didn't miss including any details.

EDIT: I've changed most of the names to English since this is a much larger text to read in multiple languages.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but if you want a better one with suggestions for improvement, I'd suggest you post a complete [repro] of the problem, because I don't know, e.g. how you compare the iterators.

Comment: Sorry about that. Iterator comparation returns true if both the `Letra`s they point to are equal in all data members. How do I share the MRE? Do I post the code here or upload it someplace else?

Comment: You should minimize it so far that it can be posted here as [edit] to the question. That means removing all code that is not necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: If you haven't yet read [ask], you may want to. If you have read it, you may want to review it again. That covers things like "Do I post the code here?" (Answer: yes)

Comment: Thanks for you help @walnut, I've included a full MRE now. Sorry for taking so long, my computer froze in the process :(

Answer (score 3):

```
TreeLetras::const_iterator :: const_iterator (Letra letra)
    :it (&letra)
{ }
```

This *always* stores to `it` a pointer to a variable that it local to the constructor (the parameter `letra`). Using that pointer later will probably cause undefined or unspecified behavior, because the local variable will be destroyed when the constructor returns.

You are not storing a pointer to the passed `Letra`, but the copy in the parameter. But even if you did take the argument by-reference, you would still be storing a pointer to a temporary object that will be destroyed after the line `return const_iterator(Letra());`.

---

Although I am not sure that this is what you want or the best approach to your problem:

If you want to store an iterator to an instance of a `Letra` that represents null/end, then you need to make sure that that instance survives at least as long as the iterator itself. One way to achieve this is to give the instance static storage duration:

```
TreeLetras::const_iterator TreeLetras :: cend () const {
    static Letra cend_letra;
    return const_iterator(cend_letra);
}
```

but the constructor must then take the argument by-reference:

```
TreeLetras::const_iterator :: const_iterator (const Letra& letra)
```

Comment: How should I make it so that it returns the passed `Letra`? Do I make a different constructor or change the `cend` function all the way? I'm completely lost on how to solve this issue... Wouldn't passing it by reference really store it until the operation in the loop is done? I'm at a loss here to be honest.

Comment: @Groctel The code in your question is too fragmented for me to really understand what you want to do, but `const_iterator(Letra());` is the wrong approach in any case.